# Need to extract ID's from a JSON file

Tags: json, parsing, extract

I have just started coding and I need to extract user ID's from a JSON file.

The ID's are mixed in with usernames and comments, and I'm not entirely sure how I can extract them so I'm left with:

> "pk": 12345678
>
> "pk": 87654321
>
> "pk": 12345678

Here is the JSON file I've been attempting to parse:
http://pastebin.com/CXNe2DCT

Also, I was wondering if it would be possible to parse just the user ID's (iterate through the list) as every other "pk" value is a comment and I just need the user ID's, not the comment ID's.

The comment "pk" values are longer also.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using a library like jQuery.

```
jQuery.getJSON("http://pastebin.com/download.php?i=CXNe2DCT", 
    function(data) {
        for (var i=0; i<data.items.length; i++) { 
            var userId = data.items[i].user.pk;
            console.log(userId);
        }
    } 
);
```

Comment: Is there anyway to use this script without having to upload it to pastebin? For example I want to use the script with a local JSON file?